# doing an update or an insert with sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a website for fantasy golf.  I use php to read an xml file and update the sql database using the following

```
foreach($field->field->children() as $player){

    $lastname = ($player['last_name']);
    $firstname = ($player['first_name']);

    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname); 
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);  
    $sSQL = "UPDATE `Sheet1` Set InField= 1 WHERE LastName = '$lastname' AND Firstname = '$firstname'";
    $result = mysql_query($sSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

This updates the database INFIELD column with the players on the xml file.  My question is how would I go about adding that player to the database if he isn't in it already?  So almost like doing and if not in the database--insert new record?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either use `REPLACE`, or use `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a unique key on `(LastName, FirstName)`, then use:

```
INSERT INTO Sheet1 (LastName, FirstName, InField)
VALUES ('$lastname', '$firstname', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE InField = 1
```

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: so if there are other columns they won't be changed if its aduplicate correct?  I have a column called TeamName that I am worried about.  if its an insert the name will be null but as a duplicate it wont change correct?

Comment: That's correct. When the key is duplicated, all it does is update what you specify. Isn't this explained clearly in the documentation? Have you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you condition it.

```
player =mysql_query(select player_in_table from players_table where player_in_table = playerx)

if(mysql_num_row(player) = 1){
 //update
} else {
 //update
}
```